# How can i make power query read ".dss" files?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Im trying to make a dashboard on Power BI with the .dss files from simulations of HEC-HMS to show results of time series datas, but they are inside a ".dss" file and power query says that: "we don't recognize the format of the first file"

How can I open those ".dss" files inside the power query ?

see a pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RydH1.png)

Thanks! Waiting help.

Comment: You can't, dss files are not supported, you need to convert them to a file format that PBI will use, like csv, tsv etc

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you might be looking for:
[HEC-DSS File and HEC-DSSVue – Gridded Data](https://rashms.com/blog/hec-dss-file-and-hec-dssvue-gridded-data/):

Quote:

> HEC-DSS, USACE Hydrologic Engineering Center Data Storage System, is a type of database system to store data primarily for hydrologic and hydraulic modeling (*.dss file). HEC-DSSVue is a tool to view, edit, and visualize a HEC-DSS file. Unlike other commercial or open source databases, HEC-DSS is not a relational database: HEC-DSS uses blocks (records) to store data within a HEC-DSS file and each HEC-DSS file can have numerous blocks (records), In addition to time series data and paired data in HEC-DSS, gridded data can also be stored in a HEC-DSS file.

HEC-DSSVue can be downloaded from here:
https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-dssvue/